# HttpClient.execute error =(

Tags: java, android, eclipse, apache, android-asynctask

And Error's are:

> error opening trace file:No Such file or directory(2);
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Manager is shut down. at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.SingleClientConnManager.assertStillUp(SingleClientConnManager.java:174)
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.SingleClientConnManager.getConnection(bla
>   bla bla .java:212)
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.SingleClientConnManager$1.getConnection(---.java:190)
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:326)
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.xecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)

```
and more...

public class ReqClass {
    public static final String TAG = ReqClass.class.getSimpleName();
    //creating new ResClass object
    ResClass resp = new ResClass(); 
    //sending request
    HttpResponse response;
    //making the request - containst (url,header,entity);
    HttpPost request;
    //New HTTP Client
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    //our code in JSON or XML to Send Request
    private String s;
    //This variable contains the total number of keys
    private int size;

    // Map
    Map<String,String> code = new HashMap<String, String>();

    // Adding only Key Value parameters
    public void addparametr (String key, String value){                 
        code.put(key,value);
    }

    public String getS(){
        return s;
    }

    //Adding Key Value and size of new map.
    public void addparametr (String key, String value, int nOfValues){    
    }

    public void Build(String lang){
        //List Of keys
        List<String> keys=new ArrayList<String>(code.keySet());
        //k = keys; v = values;
        String k="",v="";
        // size = size of Map;
        size=code.size();
        // if we want to make our JSON Code to send Request
        if (lang=="json"){                                                 
            s="";
            s+="{";
            for (int i=0; i<size; i++){
                k=keys.get(i);
                v=code.get(k);
                if (i==size-1) s=s+'"'+k+'"'+": "+'"'+v+'"';
                else s=s+'"'+k+'"'+": "+'"'+v+'"'+',';
            }

            s=s+"}";
        }

        if (lang =="xml"){                                                 
            s="";
            s+="<code>";
            for (int i=0; i<size; i++){
                k=keys.get(i);
                v=code.get(k);
                s=s+'<'+k+'>'+v+"</"+k+'>';
            }
            s=s+"</code>";
        }
    }

    // The Send Request Method - need link parameter and our JSON or XML code
    public ResClass SendR (String url, String lang){                         
        String valueOfSize = String.valueOf(size);
        request= new HttpPost(url);
        //adding a Header
        request.addHeader("Header - Request Size", valueOfSize);
        //adding request's body (Entity)
        HttpEntity entity;
        try {
            entity = new StringEntity(s, "UTF-8");
            request.setEntity(entity);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }               
        BackGroundTask doItInBackGround = new BackGroundTask();
        doItInBackGround.execute();

        //closing our connection
        httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        return resp;
    }
    private class BackGroundTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                //execute - means sending
                response = httpClient.execute(request);
                //adding new response to our Response Class
                resp.addNewResponse(response);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception caught: ", e);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `getConnectionManager().shutdown()` just after starting `AsyncTask` so before executing `doInBackground` method connection is shutdown . so use `onPostExecute` for  close connection as:

```
protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
      // call shutdown()  here
        httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();    
 }
```

Comment: Thanks) it works) but... why i can't get my response from the web?

Comment: protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
super.onPostExecute(result);
HttpEntity entity=response.getEntity();
String str=entity.toString();
   httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
Log.v("Json=", str);
}

Comment: @user3289413 : try to debug flow and values in variables when `onPostExecute`

Comment: it writes - Json = org.apache.http.conn.BasicManagedEntity@411d39e0

Comment: @user3289413 : use this line also `String str = EntityUtils.toString(entity); `